# Wheezy or Squeeze [Raspbian]

Tags: operating-systems

Which of these is better for use as a programmer device, internet navigation and stability?
Raspbian Squeeze or Wheezy ?
Or just which is better for use now without problem ?

Comment: Two versions of the same thing.  Really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I think both are quite similar, but I would recommend Wheezy because it's more popular then Squeeze.

Comment: Thank you, is it what i've searched.
I'm using Squeeze yet, but i already had Wheezy in her place, but i installed Squeeze because had soft-float.

Comment: @Edilson soft-float is bad, it means the software is doing conversions to perform non-integer (fractional) calculations, hard-float means the chip is doing the work on a hardware floating point unit (FPU) which should perform much faster.